# Why do I have to clean twice in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm not sure if this is specific to 2010.  But, when I do a clean, I get several errors saying "Cannot unregister assembly XXX.dll.  Could not load file or assembly XXX or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified."  However, if I clean again, it works.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: I suspect this only happens in a specific project...?

Comment: Yes, this only happens for specific projects, and each of them is marked "Make assembly COM-visible".  The file does exist on the system after first clean and is removed upon second clean.  The assemblies are copied to a different location in a post build event, but I'm not sure if that matters.  I'm wondering if there's some conflict in dependencies.  I really don't know what more info I could give.  If you have ideas, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into and [posted](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/8464cbfd-9c29-4755-a972-8ca4765e2dbc) about this recently and found that, from the sounds of things, this is an issue with MSBuild itself and the way it resolves dependencies. My situation is slightly different from yours, though: When I run Clean through the VS IDE, it goes off without a hitch, but when I run the Clean MSBuild task, I run into the error you opened this thread with.

In my case (I'm attempting to automate our build with MSBuild), the quick and dirty fix was to use the Exec task instead of the MSBuild task to clean (and build) the solution. For the Exec task's Command parameter, I use devenv instead of devenv.exe--although this still requires an installation of VS on the build machine, unfortunately.

I suppose another option (requiring more time than I have now) might be either to write a custom task that correctly determines dependencies and runs "Clean" against each in proper order, or write one which catches the "Could not load file...' exception and loops through the clean task until it the exception no longer pops up. (This latter seems more brute-force in approach, but might be quicker.) I'm kind of new to this, so both ideas might just be worth no more than a quick flushing.

In either case, if since starting this thread you've come up with a solution, I'd love to hear about it. Good luck.